# Forcing youtube to be cached throught cache_peer in squid

Tags: proxy, youtube, squid, peer

I would like to force a squid proxy to use a proxy cache peer form everything related to Youtube.

My main squid server is on server A, it is a realy simple setup, with nearly no rules, everything is authorized.

Server A is linked to server B via OpenVPN. Server B also have a squid proxy set up and works well (tested with ssh tunnel, no problem).

On server A I have added theses rules :

```
acl youtube_videos_regx url_regex -i ^http://[^/]+\.youtube\.com/videoplayback\?
acl youtube_videos_regx url_regex ^http://(.*?)/get_video\?
acl youtube_videos_regx url_regex ^http://(.*?)/videodownload\?
acl youtube_videos_regx url_regex ^http://(.*?)/videoplayback\?
acl youtube_videos dstdomain .youtube.com
acl youtube_videos dstdomain .youtube-nocookie.com
acl youtube_videos dstdomain .googlevideo.com
acl youtube_videos dstdomain .ytimg.com
cache_peer 10.4.0.1 parent 3128 0 proxy-only no-query connect-timeout=5
cache_peer_access 10.4.0.1 allow youtube_videos
cache_peer_access 10.4.0.1 allow youtube_videos_regx
cache_peer_access 10.4.0.1 deny all
```

But this doesn't seems to works :

```
1383861430.377    578 192.168.0.103 TCP_MISS/200 192976 GET http://r9---sn-5hn7ym7e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback? - HIER_DIRECT/208.117.250.14 application/octet-stream
1383861430.636    935 192.168.0.103 TCP_MISS/200 238032 GET http://r9---sn-5hn7ym7e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback? - HIER_DIRECT/208.117.250.14 application/octet-stream
1383861430.642   2353 192.168.0.103 TCP_MISS/200 238032 GET http://r9---sn-5hn7ym7e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback? - HIER_DIRECT/208.117.250.14 application/octet-stream
1383861432.467    617 192.168.0.103 TCP_MISS/200 192976 GET http://r9---sn-5hn7ym7e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback? - HIER_DIRECT/208.117.250.14 application/octet-stream
```

Sometimes it works :

```
1383860987.725    125 192.168.0.103 TCP_MISS/204 353 GET http://r20---sn-5hn7ym7r.googlevideo.com/generate_204 - FIRSTUP_PARENT/10.4.0.1 text/html
```

Could it be because of the data type ?

If so, I don't know what kind of rule to add.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found how to solve my problem.

I just have to add this to my config file :

```
never_direct allow youtube_videos
never_direct allow youtube_videos_regx
```

These 2 lines, force squid to not use direct connection to my 2 acl.